# Getting bundle with intent null, Intent issued from helper object

Tags: android, android-intent

I am  sending an intent to start an activity from broadcast receiver using a helper object as follows:

Broadcast receiver code:
    MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
 onReceive(){
     new Helper(this).startMyActivity();
}
```

Code in my helper object:

```
  Helper{

   private Context myContext;
   public Helper(Context c){
      myContext=c;
   }
  public void startMyActivity(){
             Intent i=new Intent(myContext,MyActivity.class);
           i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           i.putExtra("code", 1);
           myContext.startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

But when I try to extract out the bundle in the activity MyActivity, I get null value:

```
MyActivity extends Activity{

  onResume(){
    Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
    int c=b.getInt("code");
 }
}
```

Why am I getting the bundle null?

Comment: have you tried same code in onCreate of Activity?

Comment: why are you using Helper class?? you can directly pass the argument rt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to override `onNewIntent(Intent)` in the `Activity` and explicitly tell it to use the new `Intent`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.It helped. But what is the difference it creates by setting a new intent.

Comment: You're very welcome! And you're basically replacing the previous-calling Intent with the newer one

Answer (score 0):

I think,

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

is the problem, . Comment the line and try it.

or you can get the value from

```
Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();
int k = receiverIntent.getIntExtra(name, defaultValue)
```

Comment: But I need that as well as I want the activity to be placed in a new task.

Comment: try with the second method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
int c = getIntent().getIntExtra("code", 0);
```

Comment: I tried that, problem not solved.Can it be because that the activity was already open.